# I left my eggs in the car for almost a day

Tags: food-safety, eggs

I bought eggs last night and accidentally left them in the car. It was in the 30s last night, but my husband has the car and the eggs are still in there and the temperature rose to 63. Are they still safe to eat? They are store bought pasture raised. Please help!

Comment: temperature in F or C. For C you might have cooked the eggs.

Answer (score 2):

They might be okay, but it depends on exactly what temperature they got to, and if there was condensation.  Okay is also relative as everyone has different levels of acceptable risk.

If they get too cold, even after thawing back to refrigerator temperatures they will still be solid.  It makes them difficult to cook with, so you might want to just dispose of them.  (It’s possible that hard boiled eggs might be okay, but I’ve never tried it)

If they didn’t freeze, the issue is condensation if you’re in the US… moisture on the eggshell can pull any sort of bacteria or similar into the egg.  Eggs with their bloom intact (typically sold unrefrigerated) don’t have this problem.

Washed at room temperature are estimated to age about as quickly as a week at refrigeration, assuming they don’t have the condensation issues.  If they were in a cardboard (not plastic or styrofoam) container, and they’re not showing signs of cracking, and I wasn’t cooking for children, elderly people, or anyone with a weakened immune system, I would check an egg, and if they’re still liquid, I would probably use them.

However, I would use them immediately, in a dish that cooks the eggs fully.  I would probably take the opportunity to clean out whatever’s in the fridge and make a frittata or a quiche.